# Why Do We Need asio::co_spawn?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

Usually when working with coroutines, I can think of the way they execute by dividing the coroutine to the part *before* the first `co_await` and the part that comes *after* it.
The part before can usually execute directly on the stack of the calling thread whereas the part after it is scheduled for execution by some executor.

This means that if I have a coroutine, I can simply call it directly from a regular function (in a 'detached' manner).

However, in most [examples](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/talking-async/blob/master/episode1/step_1.cpp) of asio, a coroutine is invoked via `asio::co_spawn`.

Take for example this coroutine that communicate between server and client:

```
awaitable<void> server_to_client(proxy_state_ptr state)
{
    std::array<char, 1024> data;

    for (;;)
    {
      auto n = co_await state->server.async_read_some(buffer(data), use_awaitable);

      co_await async_write(state->client, buffer(data, n), use_awaitable);
    }    
}
```

The function that initiates the read-write sequence does so using `asio::co_spawn` (always in 'detached' mode). The same goes for the invocation of the coroutine that first accept the connection.

So why and when `asio::co_spawn` is necessary? When should it be used? What can happen if I invoke an asio coroutine directly without using `co_spawn` (let's say, from my main thread)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can simply call it directly from a regular function (in a 'detached' manner)

Yes, but if you don't provide an executor, it never continues.

`asio::co_spawn` is a simple way of tying an awaitable to an executor, and simple is what you want in an example.